# WHERE NOT price = (SELECT price FROM Products) doesn't work. (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table with product and prices and I'm asked to make code where it filters out the products that have same price as some other product from the same list. Well I made this:

```
SELECT name
FROM Products
WHERE NOT price = (SELECT price FROM Products);
```

Amazing I know. It seems to work somewhat, but when it came to situation where table was like this:

```
   Product      Price
+-----------+------------+
|tomato     |    1.00    |
+-----------+------------+
|potato     |    2.00    |
+-----------+------------+
|rock       |    3.00    |
+-----------+------------+
|hot tamale |    4.00    |
+-----------+------------+
```

Now for some reason, even if it worked in all the other tests I had, it gives me this:

```
     
+-----------+
|potato     |
+-----------+
|rock       |                         
+-----------+
|hot tamale |
+-----------+
```

Instead of the right answer:

```
+-----------+
|tomato     |
+-----------+
|potato     |
+-----------+
|rock       |
+-----------+
|hot tamale |
+-----------+
```

Anyone who can clear this out for my tiny mind :d? I'm in the very beginning of my journey in SQL so try to keep it simple.

Comment: And I think the reason it works on the other tests, was because in other tests the first price was always the duplicate. So I think the problem here has something to do with this code always testing the price with itself first.

Comment: I don't even understand what your query does.  How do you expect it to spit out the correct result???

Comment: Also in your example, how do you get the answer?  All are different price.

Comment: Are you saying that the query you wrote is not throwing an error? I don't believe you. The sub-select returns a set of various prices (distinct or not doesn't even matter) - as many as there are rows in the Products table. Since you use that in an equality condition, this will throw an error whenever Products has two or more rows. Would you like to reconsider what you wrote?

Comment: Umm hmm. I aint too good explaining these things in English, but Monika's answer was the right one. My query was just desperate try to use my limited knowledge on this topic. I think if I included some other examples, this would have been bit easier for outsider to understand :d.

Comment: @HuManatee - while Monika's answer is correct, it is inefficient. I showed you a more direct way in a separate answer.

Comment: And no it didn't give me errors in my SQL Trainer, even if it may hard to belive heh. Dunno why so passive agressive : D.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) over (partition by price) as cnt
      from products p
     ) p
where cnt = 1;
```

This counts the number of rows that have the same price and returns those rows where the price is unique.

Comment: My course have not guided me thru window functions yet so that would not work in this situation : (

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can use group by:

```
    create table products (product varchar2(10) , price number);
    
    insert into products values('tomato', 1);
    insert into products values('potato', 2);
    insert into products values('rock', 2);
    insert into products values('hot tamale', 4);
    
    
select * from products where price in ( 
    select price from products
    group by price
    having count(*) = 1);
```

Notice that I've changed price for 'rock' to have two products with same price to eliminate it.

Comment: Oh yes, this included the right answer. Forgot about using the HAVING. The right answer was select price from products
    group by price
    having count(*) = 1

Comment: Tho as mathguy noted I switched SELECT price with SELECT name.

Comment: @HuManatee Yes, with group by you can find product with unique prices, and then with outer select you can find names.  Happy to help :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in a single aggregate query:

```
select min(product) as product
from   products
group  by price
having count(*) = 1
;
```

The point of `min(product)` is that you must have an aggregate function (since you are not grouping by `product`); but, since you are only looking at the groups consisting of exactly one row each, `min(product)` is in fact the `product` from that single row per group.

Comment: Yes, this was what I used ;p.

Comment: @HuManatee - In your comment to Monika you said you used `select price from...` That is not right; that query will also throw an error, because `price` is not a `group by` expression. The correct query uses `MIN(product)`, as I show above. Or `MAX` if you prefer (no difference, since it's always exactly one value).

Comment: SELECT name
FROM tuotteet 
GROUP BY hinta 
HAVING count(*) = 1; Sorry, I switched price with name.